# T-SQL trigger - delete updated record if condition is met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to write a trigger for all tables in a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Enterprise database that if column `is_deleted = 1` and `change_user = 'purge'`, then delete the updated row instead of updating it.

This needs to be a dynamic trigger so that each table trigger does not need to have the table explicitly defined. The environment has over 1200 tables.

However, I only want the delete statement to delete the inserted record and not go through the entire table which I believe the below trigger would do. The environment has tables with 100+ million records and a delete statement that would run through the whole table would create a lot of overhead and would likely not keep up with 2 million transactions per hour.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [PurgeDelete]
ON [TriggerTest]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME( parent_id ) FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = @@PROCID)
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT OBJECT_NAME( parent_id ) tableName FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = @@PROCID)

    IF (ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0)
        RETURN;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM Inserted AS i
               WHERE is_deleted = 1
               AND change_user = 'purge')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'DELETE FROM ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' WHERE is_deleted = 1 AND change_user = ''purge'''
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
    END
GO

UPDATE [TriggerTest] 
SET [Description] = 'Test 1a', [is_deleted] = 1, [change_user] = 'Purge' 
WHERE [TriggerTestId] = 1

SELECT * FROM [TriggerTest];
GO
```

Comment: A trigger needs to *join* the *inserted and deleted* tables to the base table to affect only modified rows; It would probably make more sense to schedule a batch process to do your deletes based on the above criteria on a regular schedule. IF you really wanted to do it as part of the updating transaction probably an *instead of* trigger would be better.

Comment: Due to a business requirement that the delete happens immediately, a scheduled job would not be sufficient. How would an instead trigger look to meet the requirement?

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger code needs to access the `inserted` and `deleted` tables. You cannot do this with dynamic SQL, as you are then in a different scope.

In any case, if you want a dynamic trigger, I would advise instead to make a script to *generate* the triggers dynamically, but the triggers would be static once generated.

So the basic template would be like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TriggerTest_PurgeDelete
ON dbo.TriggerTest
AFTER UPDATE
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted AS i
               WHERE is_deleted = 1
               AND change_user = 'purge')
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM t
        FROM dbo.TriggerTest t
        JOIN inserted i ON i.YourPrimaryKey = t.YourPrimaryKey
        WHERE i.is_deleted = 1
          AND i.change_user = 'purge';
    END;
```

Now you just need a script that can generate this dynamically

```sql
-- user provided table/schema name here
DECLARE @schema sysname = 'dbo';
DECLARE @table sysname = 'TriggerTest';


DECLARE @quoted nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table);

DECLARE @primaryKeys nvarchar(max);

SELECT @primaryKeys = STRING_AGG(
  'i.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = t.' + QUOTENAME(c.name),
  ' AND '
  )
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
    AND i.is_primary_key = 1
JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id
    AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    AND c.column_id = i.column_id
WHERE s.name = @schema
  AND t.name = @table
  AND pk.type = 'P';


DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME(@schema + '_' + @table + '_PD') + '
ON ' + @quoted + '
AFTER UPDATE
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted AS i
               WHERE is_deleted = 1
               AND change_user = ''purge'')
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM t
        FROM ' + @quoted + ' t
        JOIN inserted i ON ' + @primaryKeys + '
        WHERE i.is_deleted = 1
          AND i.change_user = ''purge'';
    END;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You can in theory use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, which may *possibly* be more efficient if the delete will happen often, but it's also more difficult to manage, as it needs updating every time you `ALTER` any of the columns in the table.

Comment: This way, the trigger generation could check if the target table had `is_deleted` and `change_user` columns with the correct types and default constraints.

Answer (score -1):

You could use,

```
DECLARE @IsDeleted INT
DECLARE @ChangeUser VARCHAR(10)

SELECT 
   @IsDeleted = I.is_deleted
   ,@ChangeUser = I.change_user
FROM INSERTED I

IF (UPDATE (is_deleted) OR UPDATE (change_user))
    BEGIN
        IF (@IsDeleted = 1 AND @ChangeUser = 'purge')
        BEGIN 
            -- Execute the delete
        END
    END
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This doesn't actually work as it does not take into account multiple (or zero) rows in the `inserted` table, see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/. Also `UPDATE()` does not tell you if a column has actually been changed, only if it was present in the `UPDATE` statement